# Android Studio watches are not array byte

Tags: android, debugging

"Unable to evaluate the expression Code fragment expected" This show message.

Can show all Array value in setData?

Another qustion. "setData : {2,82,49,48,49,49,49,48,49,50, +2more}" <- Can show hex format?
[debugger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj2P4.png)

Comment: add the index; eg. `setData[0]`... while the variable name is a bad choice.